# How to export SharePoint search result into excel using REST Api?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api

Can anyone tell me that how can I export SharePoint search result for a particular keyword(which I passed in SharePoint search box web part) through REST API?

Comment: do you want the know about search query using REST API or the export functionality?

Comment: I want export to excel functionality.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some JS API available which can do it in better way, but i prefer the old school way to export html tabular data into excel.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table id="xyz">
            <tr>
                <td>ABC</td>
                <td>DEF</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <a id="exportData" href="" download="text.xls">Export</a>
    </body>
</html>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var tableHTML = document.getElementById('xyz').outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
        $('#exportData').prop('href', ('data:application/vnd.ms-excel, ' + tableHTML));
    })
</script>
```

The only condition is, your data need to be in tabular format and when you are saying export to excel, it must be satisfying the condition.

Comment: My data is not in table format. I am using default view of SharePoint Search result to display.